# how to formulate question about Schulz

Tags: discussion

question [Why is Donald Trump so popular?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/9743/11249) was accepted, would question [why Schulz is so popular despite failing 11th grade twice](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/20609/11249) be accepted? How can I ask the question on why people support politician who failed 11th grade twice?

Answer (score 2):

"Why is Donald Trump so popular?" asks an open, neutral, and "good faith" question. there are no assumptions or accusations in the question.

Which is different from the tone in your question. Specifically:

> How people can consider a person like this for the office?

> Does this fact show that democracy is failing in Germany?

This is a textbook example of a "rant in disguise". From [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)

> **To prevent your question from being flagged and possibly removed, avoid asking subjective questions where …**:
>
> [..]
>
> - your question is just a rant in disguise: “______ sucks, am I right?”

---

It's pretty tricky to make a question in the form of "Why would anyone vote for person X in spite of trait Y?" *not* come off as a rant, so it's probably best to avoid those sort of questions altogether. A better question might be "What are the qualification requirements to run for office?", but I suspect that won't give the answer you're looking for.

A more general "Why is Martin Schulz so popular?" would also be okay.

Comment: I'm torn 2 ways on this. One one hand, you do have a very good point re: ranting. On the other hand, a general "why is X popular" is at risk of an obvious "why wouldn't X be popular" rejoinder, and as such a rational (even if it risks being biased) explanation of why the asker wouldn't expect X to be popular may benefit narrowing the question down. I don't know anything about Schultz and my first inclination to such a question would be to close as either too broad or "unclear what you're asking" or "subjective" without clarifications in the body.